# how to combine a top command with a date column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Good day,
I need to add a Column header "TIME" that will display the current time for each time the output is executed on a new line with the following code:

```
top -b -n 1 -p 984 -o +PID -o +VIRT | sed -n '7,12p' | awk '{printf "%1s %-4s\n",$1,$5}'
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
TIME      PID     VIRT
12:00:00  984     1024
12:16:01  984     995
12:44:29  984     1008
```

(The values is only for display, not correct)

also it should be in a endless loop with interval of 10s until user stops it.
everything is executed from PIDandVIRT.sh
(Linux script)

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the `ps` command instead of `top`:

```
echo "TIME PID VSIZE"
while true ; do
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $(ps -p 984 -o pid,vsize --no-headers)"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an `awk` variable to the result of the `date` command:

```
awk -v time=$(date '+%H:%M:%S') '{printf "%s %1s %-4s\n", time, $1, $5}'
```

To get it in a loop, use `while`

```
while :; do
    top -b -n 1 -p 984 -o +PID -o +VIRT | sed -n '7,12p' | awk -v time=$(date '+%H:%M:%S') '{printf "%s %1s %-4s\n", time, $1, $5}'
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: You don't need sed when you're using awk. `cmd | sed -n '7,12p' | awk '{doSomething}'` = `cmd | awk 'NR>=7{doSomething} NR==12{exit}'` or various alternative structures. I know you just copied what the OP had but may as well show him the right way.